# Problema actualizar Next 12 a Next 13

Tags: vscode, nextjs

Tengo mi proyecto en Next 12, estoy conectado a una rama develop que es la principal.

Cree una nueva rama para actualizar a Next 13.

En esta nueva rama corri `npm install next@latest`.

Al intentar correr el proyecto recibi errores por parte de los `Links`, entonces instalé `codemod` y corri `npx @next/codemod <transform> <path>` para arreglar todos los links.

La aplicacion funcionaba perfecto, pero decidi cancelar todos los cambios y volver a mi rama develop.

En ella veo que no hay cambios, mi `package.json` mantiene la version de Next.13

Pero no puedo correr el proyecto, cuando hago `npm run dev` el servidor se levanta pero me devuelve el error de los `Links` como si estuviera intentando correr Next 13.

Cerre el vs-code, lo volvi a abrir y el error persiste. Es como si me hubiera quedado algo cacheado, porque no hay ningun cambio en el codigo que hace una hora funcionaba perfecto.

Comment: Borrar la carpeta ``node_modules``, ``.next`` y ejecutar ``npm ci`` arreglo el problema